# The localstorage of the browser sort my datas without my consent

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I created a todo list in js, the datas save by the form are sent in the local storage of the navigator. The problem is that my data save in the local storage are sorted without my opinion. The datas changes of place all alone.

The datas are save in the right order on the first picture

[image]

In the second photo here my datas change of place without my opinion

[image]

My datas save should be in that order:

- 1
- 2
- 3

```
 for ( var i = 0, len = localStorage.length; i < len; ++i ) {

  var key   = localStorage.key(i);
}
```

I expect my datas in localstorage to be in the order of their creation.

Comment: There's no order to localStorage, it's just names and values.

Comment: `I expect my datas in localstorage to be in the order of their creation.`  Why?  According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/key):  "The order of keys is user-agent defined, so you should not rely on it."

Comment: Maybe you can use a more descriptive key (as the date) and sort the keys before using it

Answer (score 1):

This should not be a problem for you if every time you obtain the data from the localStorage sort it with a method. Remember there is no order to localStorage and the data can be provided as is.

Answer (score 0):

Great, thank you. I solved my problem by creating a table that contains the length of the localsorage then I force with this to retrieve them in the order.

```
var tab = [];

 for ( var j = 0, len = localStorage.length; j < len; ++j ) {
            nombres.push(j)
 }


var key   = localStorage.getItem(tab[i])
var data = JSON.parse(key);
```

Enjoy.